# How to implement the inverse of "intercalate" (splitting a string into pieces on a character) using functions from "base"?

Tags: string, list, haskell, split

I wanted to split a string on newlines and I was surprised that I could not find the inverse function to [`intercalate "\n"`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v%3aintercalate). That is, a function that splits a string into pieces on new lines (or according to some other predicate).

Note that `lines` and `words` do something different. For example

```
intercalate "\n" (lines "a\n") == "a"
```

There is a similar function function [`splitOn`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.2/docs/Data-List-Split.html#v%3asplitOn) in the *split* library. I could also write such a function myself directly:

```
splitOn :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitOn p = map reverse . g []
  where
    g rs []                 = [rs]
    g rs (x:xs) | p x       = rs : g [] xs
                | otherwise = g (x : rs) xs
```

but I wonder **if it could be constructed more easily using only functions from [base](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base).**

Comment: This isn't the same as `splitOn` from Data.List.Split.  That one has the type signature `[a] -> [a] -> [[a]]`, while yours has the equivalent of `a -> [a] -> [[a]]`.  The difference is splitting on a substring or splitting on a single character.

Comment: But we have `sepBy` from `ParserCombinators`, http://www.haskell.org/platform/doc/2013.2.0.0/packages/parsec-3.1.3/doc/html/Text-ParserCombinators-Parsec-Combinator.html

Comment: This `splitOn` is like `Data.List.Split.splitWhen`.

Comment: Do you have to use the `String` type? Both `Text` and `ByteString.Char8` have `split` functions for breaking up a string.

Comment: @LukeTaylor Unfortunately yes. The library I'd like to contribute to doesn't use any of them and I feel that adding a dependency just for this function wouldn't be very nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Nikita Volkov points out, the restriction "only Prelude functions" doesn't make it very easy, but here's one option:

```
splitWhen p [] = [[]]
splitWhen p l  = uncurry (:) . fmap (splitWhen p . drop 1) . break p $ l
```

This uses the `Functor` instance for `(,) a` as an alternative to `Control.Arrow.second` (to avoid a messier lambda expression), which works without importing anything (ghci says "defined in 'GHC.Base'"), but I'm not sure if that actually belongs in the `Prelude`, since I can't find it in the Haskell Report.

**Edit:** Being allowed to use other functions from `base` doesn't even help me that much. In any case I would use `second` instead of `fmap` because I think it adds a little clarity. With `unfoldr`, using a `Maybe` for the seed to distinguish the end of the string from an empty part (or empty line in the example):

```
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import Control.Arrow (second)
import Data.List (unfoldr)

splitWhen p = unfoldr (second check . break p <$>) . Just
  where
    check []       = Nothing
    check (_:rest) = Just rest

-- or cramming it into a single line with 'Data.Maybe.listToMaybe'
splitWhen' p =
  unfoldr (second (\rest -> tail rest <$ listToMaybe rest) . break p <$>) . Just
```

Comment: Sorry, I stated the question wrong. My intent was using only functions from "base", without requiring additional library packages, not just the Prelude module.

Answer (score 5):

If the composition of more primitive functions is what you're looking for, then I can think of no other way than something based on `unfoldr` and `break`, but `unfoldr` is not in `Prelude`.

Anyway, I think you're well aware that `Prelude` is far from what many of us want it to be, so there's no surprise that it can't solve even such a seemingly trivial problem. The general problem with `Prelude` seems to be that it's mispurposed: the module aims to provide things that are enough to play with Haskell as part of an introduction, as even its name suggests, but since there is no standard "base" module, Haskellers tend to see it as one.

Comment: Sorry, I stated the question wrong. My intent was using only functions from "base", without requiring additional library packages, not just the Prelude module.